# Vuex input with v-model not reactive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I try to explain it as simple as possible. I have something like this. Simple Vue root, Vuex store and input with v-model inside navbar id.

That input is not reactive... Why?!

[image]

[image]

HTML

```
<div id="navbar">
    <h2>@{{ test }}</h2>
    <input v-model="test" />
</div>
```

store.js

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    test: 'test'
  },
  getters: {
    test (state) {
      return state.test
    }
  }
})
```

Vue Root

```
import { store } from './app-store.js'

new Vue({
  el: '#navbar',
  store,
  computed: {
    test () {
      return this.$store.getters.test
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 29):

You're binding to a computed property. In order to **set** a value on a computed property you need to write `get` and `set` methods.

```
computed:{
    test:{
        get(){ return this.$store.getters.test; },
        set( value ){ this.$store.commit("TEST_COMMIT", value );}
    }
}
```

And in your store

```
mutations:{
    TEST_COMMIT( state, payload ){
        state.test=payload;
    }
}
```

Now when you change the value of the input bound to test, it will trigger a commit to the store, which updates its state.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to use `v-model` for that. Instead, use  `@input="test"` in your input field and in the your `methods` hook:

```
 test(e){
    this.$store.dispatch('setTest', e.target.value)
 }
```

Inside your `Vuex` store:

In `mutations`:

```
   setTest(state, payload){
      state.test = payload
   },
```

In `actions`:

```
setTest: (context,val) => {context.commit('setTest', val)},
```

The input should now be reactive and you should see the result in `@{{test}}`

Here is an example of how I handle user input with Vuex: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gmROQq

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use `v-model` with Vuex (with actions/mutations firing on each change) by using my library:

https://github.com/yarsky-tgz/vuex-dot

```
<template>
  <form>
    <input v-model="name"/>
    <input v-model="email"/>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
  import { takeState } from 'vuex-dot';

  export default {
    computed: {
      ...takeState('user')
        .expose(['name', 'email'])
        .commit('editUser') // payload example: { name: 'Peter'}
        .map()
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Self promoting answers are not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The `computed` property is one-way. If you want two-way binding, make a setter as the other answers suggest or use the `data` property instead.

```
import { store } from './app-store.js'

new Vue({
  el: '#navbar',
  store,
  // computed: {
  //   test() {
  //     return this.$store.getters.test;
  //   }
  // }
  data: function() {
    return { test: this.$store.getters.test };
  }
});
```

But a setter is better to validate input value.